# Why does my dynamic array work without being resized?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, dynamic-arrays

I'm working on dynamic arrays for my c++ course, but I'm confused about the behavior of my dynamic arrays.  For example, if I run this code:

```
int* myDynamicArr = new int[3];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    myDynamicArr[i] = i + 1;
    cout << myDynamicArr[i] << endl;
}
```

I would expect it to not work since I only declared it as size 3.  But when I run it, it prints out 0-9.  Same thing if I do this:

```
char* myCharArr = new char[2];
strcpy(myCharArr, "ThisIsALongString");
cout << myCharArr;
```

It prints the full string even though it seems like it should fail.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the world of "Undefined Behavior" [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ does not perform bounds checking on arrays.  So when you read or write past the bounds of an array you trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With undefined behavior, your program may crash, it may output strange results, or it may (as in your case) appear to work properly.

Just because it *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.